# Dcc.inputs is not updating and autmatically reset to default values

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I am using dcc.inputs and one ‘apply’ button in my layout…After updating all the input Once i click the apply button, all the iupdated values got replaced by default values automatically… the values are not updated. How to correct this issue such that the input containers should contain the latest input values.

I tried some callbacks but the same problem persists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Then also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And finally please learn how to create a [mre] to show us, and how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.